# quickFix - sending XML message for Fix 4.4 failing validation

Tags: quickfix

while sending a FIX 4.4 xml message msgType as n - the message fails validation (yes, we perform validation while sending fix message out) - with error.

```
    quickfix.FieldException: Invalid MsgType, field=-1
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.checkMsgType(DataDictionary.java:699)
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.validate(DataDictionary.java:647)
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.validate(DataDictionary.java:624)
```

Searched everywhere but not able to get much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the standard data dictionaries for FIX 4.4 in QuickFIX don't contain message type n (msgtype="n"), you will have to add the message type yourself. Incidentally I have never seen XMLnonFIX messages before so had to look it up first!

Answer (score 1):

that was the issue. Making following ammendments to the dictionary solved the issue.

```
<message name="XML_non_FIX" msgtype="n" msgcat="app">
<field name="XmlDataLen" required="N"/>
<field name="XmlData" required="N"/>
</message>
```